# How to show Sharepoint Site Usage Statistics in a page?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss, sharepoint-api

What's the best way of showing site usage statistics in a page? I know I can view the stats from `/_layouts/SpUsageSite.aspx` and from designer also, but if I want to show this information in a customized way for a target audience, how can I show this data in a page? at least I need to show "recently visited pages".

Comment: A web part is the way to go. Unfortunately, I only know 2010 web part development which is vastly different from my understanding.

Comment: @chris-felstead do you know the C# way? i think the coding bit will be same for both 2007 and 2010, if i can extract only top 10 recently visited pages in a site collection and their hit count, that will also do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all but I solved my problem quite easily, I simply used

`spweb.GetUsageData(SPUsageReportType, SPUsagePeriodType)`

didn't know SPWeb has such method, its enough for my requirement.
thank you @Chris SPUsage is also one solution I think, I'll try it next time

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SharePoint class for return reports. See the SPUsage class on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spusage.aspx)

Comment: +1 there are lots of usage classes in the namespace - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463219.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the SP main page, go to the Site Actions, Site Settings, Modify All Site Settings and then select site Usage reports under the Site Administration column.

Once the page loads and shows you the stats. copy the url out of the browser  and then ad that to a List or annoucements and then add that to your page as a web part with a hyper link to the stats report.

you could also create a new web-page and then insert an I-frame object with the stats report url and then link the new page to the parent site using a List.

Comment: Appreciate your effort, but the problem is most of the cases that page is admin only. It's not wise to let user view that page. If you need only a specific information why show the entire page? I already got the method I wanted. Please have a look at my answer.